# Django Celery - Scheduled task will remove itself from the schedule after several hours

Tags: python, django, celery

I've got a Django site used for crash reporting that utilizes Celery to regularly update the site with new crashes as they come in.  Everything generally works fine, EXCEPT that after an arbitrary interval that could be anywhere between 3 hours and 5 days, two of the scheduled tasks no longer fire.  There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of rhyme or reason to why they stop, although a higher rate of crashes appears to shorten the interval in which it can occur.

The things that differentiate these two tasks are:

- They're the only two NOT run on the box the site and database are hosted on
- They're the only two scheduled for every 20 minutes (others have either longer or shorter intervals)

They both use the task decorators of:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='*/3'),
           ignore_result=True,
           queue=WorkQueue.LOCAL,
           options={'queue': WorkQueue.LOCAL})
```

Things I've noticed:

- Both worker boxes run a celery beat, but the boxthe site is hosted on appears to be calling both 'bad' tasks once a minute instead of once every 20 like the other box is supposed to.  I double-checked to make sure, and I didn't change the rate on them (it's still hour='*/3').  It's also scheduling them when the other box's beat misses it.
- One of those tasks sometimes stops for other reasons than being unscheduled, though that is the primary issue it has.  It basically calls an '.exe' with a bunch of command options.  Once or twice a month that app will 'stop responding' to Windows and I will have to restart the workers.  The other thing that has happened (which I believe I fixed) was that the Task Scheduler (Windows, not Celery) was starting several batches of concurrent workers while only one is supposed to be running at a time.
- Neither of those things appears when the task is 'unscheduled'.
- There are no 'PENDING' tasks in RabbitMQ when this happens.

Any ideas? If I need to provide more information, just let me know.

Edit: A snippet of the log from the workers right before the scheduler drops the task:

`[2014-09-07 00:06:00,874: WARNING/Worker-1] Submitted new modules for report 00e6d5af-21de-4981-9c9f-dcc002140906
[2014-09-07 00:06:00,874: WARNING/Worker-1] Retrieving report from db.
[2014-09-07 00:06:00,874: WARNING/Worker-1] Marking complete/processed 00e6d5af-21de-4981-9c9f-dcc002140906
[2014-09-07 00:06:00,921: INFO/MainProcess] Task sirocco.crashes.tasks.analyze_windows_crash[5313821c-3a43-47fa-9a27-c6a
6fba41b03] succeeded in 8.81399989128s: None
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,180: WARNING/Worker-1] CDB exited with code 0 in 12.043 seconds
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,180: WARNING/Worker-1] Created new digest 38ec8b36230e783298d53dcc58ad655502d57b755c7d23e9bb9b34892
8bdb941
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,197: WARNING/Worker-1] Attempting to submit 821d6cd2-07fb-491d-886c-574682140906
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,197: WARNING/Worker-1] [821d6cd2-07fb-491d-886c-574682140906] Submit analysis to DB
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,211: WARNING/Worker-1] Got existing signature 205
[2014-09-07 00:06:04,243: WARNING/Worker-1] Submitting modules for 821d6cd2-07fb-491d-886c-574682140906:
[2014-09-07 00:06:05,569: WARNING/Worker-1] Submitted new modules for report 821d6cd2-07fb-491d-886c-574682140906
[2014-09-07 00:06:05,569: WARNING/Worker-1] Retrieving report from db.
[2014-09-07 00:06:05,569: WARNING/Worker-1] Marking complete/processed 821d6cd2-07fb-491d-886c-574682140906
[2014-09-07 00:06:05,615: INFO/MainProcess] Task sirocco.crashes.tasks.analyze_windows_crash[b59f9846-56d7-40fd-a235-96a
4349f20cc] succeeded in 13.5089998245s: None`

Comment: Can you post celery log before they stop responding?

Comment: Do you mean the log from when Windows stops responding, or from when the task gets unscheduled?  Also, did you mean the beat log, or the worker log? In the case of the workers, the log looks exactly like when it's working, except that nothing new comes after it until the beat/workers are restarted.  The last worker running will finish its' task, and they'll just sit there waiting. Regardless, I'll post a snippet of it.  The beat log will just continue to schedule the other tasks as if nothing happened.

Comment: Which celery version are you using?

Comment: I believe it's 3.1.12 (Cipater).

Comment: Can you upgrade to latest version & check if the worker is crashing again?

Comment: I'll attempt this tomorrow when I get back to the office. As far as I can tell, though, it never actually crashed. Was there a fix released for a similar problem in the latest patch?

Comment: In the process of upgrading, I discovered that I was in fact running two different versions of celery.  Oddly enough, this did not cause any complaints from either node.  I upgraded both to the latest and have not had any random misses since.  Closing my question.